# Rebind generic interface in Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have several projects referencing a package containing generic interface

```
public interface IHandler<T> where T : class
{
    void Handle(T data);
}
```

These projects contain `IHandler<>` implementations and Ninject modules with bindings from interface to implementations.

I want to create decorator for all `IHandler<>` implementations

```
public class HandlerDecorator<T> : IHandler<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IHandler<T> decorated;

    public HandlerDecorator(IHandler<T> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(T data)
    {
        // some logic 
    }
}
```

and decorate all registered bindings of `IHandler<>` automatically. E.g. if there exists binding of `IHandler<string>` and `StringHandler` then target should be changed to `new HandlerDecorator<string>(stringHandlerInstance)`.

Is it possible in Ninject? Or I should rewrite all Ninject modules code?

Answer (score 0):

As you can not access any meaningful binding information once the bindings are created, there is no direct way to accomplish this.
You could, however, use [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) to search for all `IHandler<T>` implementations and bind / re-bind them with the decorator. In Ninject, using a decorator requires a binding for the decorator and one for the decorated implementation. In case you always use the same decorator, it can be simplified by using a generic binding for the decorator. This would be:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IHandler<>)).To(typeof(HandlerDecorator));
```

(Or using `Rebind` instead of `Bind` - as needed).

And the binding created by using the conventions extension should equal to:

```
kernel.Bind<IHandler<string>>()
      .To<StringHandler>()
      .WhenInjectedInto<HandlerDecorator<string>>();
```

This is achieved by doing something along the lines of:

```
kernel.Bind( x => x
   .FromThisAssembly()
   .SelectAllClasses()
   .InheritedFrom(typeof(IHandler))
   .Excluding(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>))
   .BindDefaultInterface()
   .Configure(b => b.WhenInjectedInto(typeof(HandlerDecorator<>)));
```